# Using REST Assured library for testing SOAP webservices

Tags: soapui, web-service

Is there a possibility of using REST Assured library for testing SOAP webservices? I have a bunch of Test Suites in SOAP UI and I need to check if there is possibility of using REST Assured. Can anyone suggest if this is possible? Many thanks for any comments.

Comment: I found you've asked same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968999/using-rest-assured-library-for-testing-soap-webservices. Please, do not cross-post a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites. More explanation and how to migrate questions you can find here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm new at StackExchange and still learning rules here ;)
Thanks for sharing link about how to cross-posting questions on Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have written this code and it is working form me:

Created a file SoapRequestFile.xml with the content:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetConversionRate>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:CurrencyFrom>USD</tem:CurrencyFrom>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:CurrencyTo>INR</tem:CurrencyTo>
         <tem:RateDate>2018-12-07</tem:RateDate>
      </tem:GetConversionRate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then here is code I have written in eclipse:

```java
@Test
public void postMethod() throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(".\\SOAPRequest\\SoapRequestFile.xml"));
         RestAssured.baseURI="http://currencyconverter.kowabunga.net";
         
         Response response=given()
                .header("Content-Type", "text/xml")
                .and()
                .body(IOUtils.toString(fileInputStream,"UTF-8"))
         .when()
            .post("/converter.asmx")
         .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .and()
                .log().all()
                .extract().response();
         
        XmlPath jsXpath= new XmlPath(response.asString());//Converting string into xml path to assert
        String rate=jsXpath.getString("GetConversionRateResult");
        System.out.println("rate returned is: " +  rate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, however not necessarily easy.

SOAP Web service is (usually) receiving HTTP requests with XML in the body and sending back HTTP responses with XML in the body.

REST-assured can send HTTP requests with any content, including XML. It can also verify XML in responses with [GPath](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_gpath).

Here's an example from [REST-assured site](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-2---xml):

> Imagine that a POST request to http://localhost:8080/greetXML returns:
>
> ```xml
> <greeting>
>    <firstName>{params("firstName")}</firstName>
>    <lastName>{params("lastName")}</lastName>
> </greeting>
> ```
>
> i.e. it sends back a greeting based on the `firstName` and `lastName`
> parameter sent in the request. You can easily perform and verify e.g.
> the `firstName` with REST assured:
>
> ```java
> given().
>          parameters("firstName", "John", "lastName", "Doe").
> when().
>          post("/greetXML").
> then().
>          body("greeting.firstName", equalTo("John")).
> ```

The problem is that SOAP Requests and SOAP Responses are usually far more complex and you will need to understand [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) descriptors yourself.

Answer (score 1):

REST-assured does not have direct support for testing SOAP services, but it is possible by manually setting the `SOAPAction` and `Content-Type` headers and doing an HTTP `POST` etc. Then you can run XPath assertions on the response like you do for normal REST services in REST-assured.

I suggest you also evaluate [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as it has built-in support for SOAP, and also makes XML manipulation a lot easier.